# Wordpress listen to $_POST in functions.php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I currently have the following function in my functions.php which checks if a username exists in the DB.

```
function check_username() {
           $username = $_POST['user'];
           if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
               $return['user_exists'] = true; 
           }
           else {
               $return['user_exists'] = false;
           }
           echo json_encode($return);
           die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
```

I'm using Ajax to call that function with an appropriate username:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://examle.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    data : {
        action : 'check_username',
        user: 'test'
    },
    success : function (json) {
        if (json.user_exists) {
            alert(json.user_exists);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that `$username` returns `null` instead of `test`. I've been trying for several hours now different combinations yet they've all returned `null`.

Assigning this makes the above php function work `$username = 'test';` so I'm pretty sure this isn't an issue with the php code.

So my question is, how do I get the variable `$username` to listen and fetch the correct parameter instead of `null`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because ajax is submitting a GET variable, and php is looking for a POST variable.  Either change ajax type to POST or change php to use $_GET['user'].

Comment: Or even better, use $_REQUEST

Comment: @Limiter Indeed that would work as well.  Just beware that $_REQUEST grabs values from all of $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE.  Some folks feel it's less secure because of that, but as long as you know what's coming it is fine.  I generally use $_REQUEST for debugging as I can more easily stuff values into a querystring than make up fake forms.

Comment: to think of it, thats true, guess I am used to my daily framework, where POST and GET are merged into a single parameters array(which also has its validation and sanitation functions built in the function that does it) and we only use that